# How to change a TextView's text to different text by pressing a Button

Tags: android

1. Im trying to make a simple decision support android application using Android Studio by answering
   a YES and NO questions. However i dont know how to code it. I want
   the question in the TextView change to different question by pressing the YES and NO
   button until it gets the final result/decision.

This code as the startup. Please help me :(

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int i=0;
TextView text;
Button YES,NO;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main6);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText("hello "+i);

    YES = (Button) findViewById(R.id.YES);
    YES.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            i=i+1;
            text.setText("hello "+i);
        }


    });
    NO = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NO);
    NO.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            i=i-1;
            text.setText("hello "+i);
        }


    });
}
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting.

Comment: what your objective can you explain me

Comment: no error at all, I just don't know how to change the text in the textview to another text by clicking the button based on the code above. The thing is the code above only change the number in ("hello"+i).

Comment: what you wan to show on textview during YES and No button click?

Comment: Please search for similar questions in stackoverflow before posting.You can easily find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It still changes the `text` on `TextView` like: (hello 1, hello 2, ...... )

**Try using different `text` for better understanding:**

```
final Button YES = (Button) findViewById(R.id.YES);
YES.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on click
        i=i+1;
        text.setText("Yes button clicked.... hello: " + i);
    }
});

final Button NO = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NO);
NO.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on click
        i=i-1;
        text.setText("No button clicked.... hello: " + i);
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

> I want to change "hello 1" to "Are you okay?" then, if he/she click on
>   YES button, the textview will display different question such as "Are
>   you happy?". And if he/she click on NO button, the textview will
>   display "Are you sad?". do you know how? after answering a few
>   question the final result will be displayed. can you help me?

**Try this:**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main6Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView text;
    Button buttonYES;
    Button buttonNO;

    ArrayList<String> questionList;
    int currentQuestion = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main6);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        buttonYES = (Button) findViewById(R.id.YES);
        buttonNO = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NO);

        // Dummy questions
        questionList = new ArrayList<String>();
        questionList.add("Are you okey?");
        questionList.add("Are you happy?");
        questionList.add("Are you sad?");
        questionList.add("Are you fine?");
        questionList.add("Are you angry?");

        showQuestion();

        buttonYES.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                currentQuestion++;
                showQuestion();
            }
        });

        buttonNO.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentQuestion++;
                showQuestion();
            }
        });
    }

    public void showQuestion() {

        if (currentQuestion < questionList.size() - 1)
        {
            text.setText(questionList.get(currentQuestion));
        }
        else
        {
            text.setText("FINISHED");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help to understand.

Comment: I know, I want to change "hello 1" to "Are you okay?" then, if he/she click on YES button, the textview will display different question such as "Are you happy?". And if he/she click on NO button, the textview will display "Are you sad?". do you know how? after answering a few question the final result will be displayed. can you help me?